# OS X 10.7, shell scripting to Windows Server 2003 shared folder

Tags: windows-server-2003, mac-osx, deployment, server-message-block

I have a remote WS2003 machine that I can remote into to manage an IIS server.

For convenience I also have the app root directly as a shared folder which I can mount in Finder on my OS X laptop.

What I want to do now is write a shell script which will deploy my files from the OS X machine to the Windows shared folder that houses the actual web application

In OS X 10.6, there was a utility called smbclient which could assist in this operation, but now that tool appears to be gone in 10.7.

So basically I am looking for alternatives, and I would accept any recommendations anyone has on one-click deploys to an IIS6/Windows Server 2003 machine from OS X

Note, these sites are static sites, not .NET sites or ASP sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at mount_smbfs ?